# Query on a temp table with user function-based calculation, no joins, how to avoid table scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to optimize this query based on the WHERE filter? I can't use computed columns for compatibility reasons. Other than that, I accept any suggestion:

```
UPDATE #ATempTable
   SET SomeTotal = (QuantityA + QuantityB + QuantityC) 
 - (dbo.fmin(dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ValueA,0)
  ,dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ROUND(ValueB,0),0)
 , ISNULL(ValueC,0))), ISNULL(round(ValueD,0), 9999999)))

 WHERE QuantityA + QuantityB + QuantityC > 
 (dbo.fmin(dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ValueA,0)
  ,dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ROUND(ValueB,0),0)
 , ISNULL(ValueC,0))), ISNULL(round(ValueD,0), 9999999)))
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. `fmax` and `fmin`are user-defined functions that return the greatest and the lowest of two given values, respectively, and are not schema-bound.

EDIT: Additional info

The #ATempTable is a temporary table inside a procedure that is called by an application, SomeTotal, QuantityA/B/C and ValueA/B/C/D are all fields of that table. And no, the code is not like that, I renamed the fields.

Comment: Are Quantities A,B, and C in the same table as Values A-D?

Comment: Yes, they are all fields of the temp table.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 R2 supports indexed views. You may want to create a view on your base table(s) and define therein the summation column and then create an index over it. This will greatly reduce the filtering time.

Comment: This is useful. It runs inside a stored procedure, though.

Comment: @dotNET . . . Can you create a view on a temporary table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I don't think so (not sure though), but he can create a permanent table in his db, create a view on top of it and use it in this SP then.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table, I would suggest that you add a column with the difference in the `where` clause:

```
diff = (QuantityA + QuantityB + QuantityC) -
 (dbo.fmin(dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ValueA,0)
  ,dbo.fmax(ISNULL(ROUND(ValueB,0),0)
 , ISNULL(ValueC,0))), ISNULL(round(ValueD,0), 9999999)));
```

You can then add an index on the new column (which I called `diff`).  This will speed up your `update` statement.

Comment: You mean a computed column?

Comment: @PedroFialho . . . You could add a computed column.  But because this is a temporary table, I would just add the column directly into the temporary table.

Comment: If it's a normal column then it's OK, because as in the question I can't use a computed column, but I still would have to update all the lines... sounds like a scan on the table and another update only on eligible rows, is that it?

Comment: @PedroFialho . . . You are creating the table somehow.  So there is not necessarily any additional scan on the table.  Do this when you create the table/insert rows into the table.  Then you have an index build.  Takes a small amount of time, and your updates will go faster.